# how to show sms failure badge in sms application using code

Tags: ios, sms, badge

The latest iOS conveniently puts a red exclamation point badge on the "Messages" app if an SMS failed to send at one point.

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't get this error badge to go away. I want to show while i send sms in my application. Can anyone help me in this by code ??

[2] I also want to show in my composeview as like in iphone we found in default setting of sms.

Comment: Is there any quick way to find the failed message and clear it? Or any way to clear the badge? Or am I doomed to have an exclamation point over my messages app forever (or at least until I spend half a day combing through my SMS history)